# Flag weight fixed at 0 on meta.codereview

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-weight

The situation is as follows:

- If a user looks at their own profile on [meta.codereview](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com), their flag weight is not displayed, suggesting it is in the normal range.
- If *I* (as a moderator) look at anybody's profile (including my own) the flag weight is displayed as 0.
- Consequently, if any user (including myself) flags something, the flag does not show up in the flags queue.

So is this a bug or were flags deliberately disabled on meta.codereview?

Comment: flags weighted zero are [suppressed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178), but don't know why zero.

Comment: Definitely a bug; fixing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the bullets in turn:

- flag weight was (incorrectly) not shown on per-site metas
- there was a bug with the twin user-creation on per-site metas; fixed
- that is expected with a zero; it was have disabled this while I investigated, but restored now

Comment: Did this only affect users who were created *after* the flag weight system was introduced? I noticed a few (fairly random) 0 weight entries on Gaming Meta, and I couldn't really find any pattern until you brought up that it was due to a bug in user-creation. Consequently, since Code Review was made after the flag weight system, that would indeed qualify every single user.

Comment: @GraceNote pretty-much, yes; the flag weight was also running in the background a while longer than seen, too. The weights have been fixed...